Recovered image does not match : CS50
I am working on the Recover assignment of the CS50 course.
Getting the error : The recovered image does not match (from the CS50 error checker). In other words, I successfully recover 50/50 JPGs, but they are all just blank white
Can't seem to figure out where the problem lies.
Tried refactoring the code a bit, but honestly im at a loss. I know it must have something to do with handling the multi-block files, but maybe im missing something even more fundamental. CS50 has been my first foray into C so I would appreciate as much elaboration as possible.
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Please add exactly one command line argument!");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *card = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char *filename = malloc(8);
    FILE *img = NULL;
    int numOfImgs = 0;

    if (card == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not access memory card.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    uint8_t buffer[512];
    while (fread(buffer, 1, 512, card) == 512)
    {
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0) {

            if (img == NULL) {
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", numOfImgs);
                img = fopen(filename, "w");
                fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, img);
            }
            else {
                fclose(img);
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", numOfImgs);
                img = fopen(filename, "w");
                fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, img);
            }
            numOfImgs++;
        }
    }

    fclose(img);
    fclose(card);
    free(filename);
    return 0;
}


Are you telling us affirmatively that your recovered images are well formed and all-white, or are you speculating that that is how they are wrong?  If the former, then are you sure that they are exactly full white (all color channels maximum intensity)?

It appears that you only write a block if it is a header block. Try deleting the two fwrites and adding one at the end of the loop.

Also, you must explicitly open the files in binary mode (even though it isn't necessary on some systems).

@WeatherVane: The assignments of the CS50 course are intended to be done in a GitHub codespace which runs on Linux. On Linux, as on all POSIX platforms, there is no difference between text mode and binary mode. So, as far as the assignment is concerned, there is no need to distinguish between text mode and binary mode.

@AndreasWenzel for portable code, be explicit. It's one letter, so it's not exactly an arduous task. If the OP later moves on to a system with different line endings, that's one more hole for them to fall into.

@WeatherVane: Yes, that is generally good advice, but it is likely confusing for OP, as the CS50 course does not teach the difference between text mode and binary mode.

The TL;DR: Remove the [two] fwrite calls. Replace them with [a single] if (img != NULL) fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, img); at the bottom of the while loop.

@CraigEstey's comment was better – there might not be any header block found. Similarly after the loop: if (img != NULL) fclose(img);

The assignment states the following:

Realize, of course, that JPEGs can span contiguous blocks. Otherwise, no JPEG could be larger than 512 B.

It appears that you are incorrectly assuming that a JPEG file will never consist of more than a single 512-byte block.
You are only writing the first 512 byte block of every recovered file to the output JPEG files. You are discarding all subsequent blocks, which is wrong.
The "walkthrough video" of the assignment contains a description of the algorithm you can use so that the subsequent blocks also get written to the JPEG output files.
As a side note, I would also like to point out that the lines
if (img == NULL) {
    sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", numOfImgs);
    img = fopen(filename, "w");
    fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, img);
}
else {
    fclose(img);
    sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", numOfImgs);
    img = fopen(filename, "w");
    fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, img);
}

can be changed to:
if (img != NULL) {
    fclose(img);
}

sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", numOfImgs);
img = fopen(filename, "w");
fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, img);

Performing this code change won't change the behavior of your program, but it will get rid of three lines of unnecessary code duplication.
